# Open visual studio 2013 solution in vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a vs 2013 project I need to open it in vs 2012 but it is not loaded when I open it in vs 2012. Do I need to change something in the csproj?

Comment: It should work just fine. The only thing you might need is to install the latest Windows SDK, which will enable you to target .NET 4.5.1 in VS2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh487283.aspx

Comment: Maybe you should of supplied some more info about what error vs presents when you try to open the solution on it. 

is it this “This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio” , have you found a solution for this error .?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I didn't understand what you advised to install from that link ..?
This : https://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx 

?

Answer (score 0):

It should just work. Right click on the solution and open with Visual Studio 2012. Do the same if you wish to open again with Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score -1):

You can try to open .sln and .csproj with any text editor and replace tools and visual studio version manually. For most visual studio versions it works. Some time is enough just to replace studio version ex: In my case I had 2012 project and I just replaced version 11 with 10 an it works under Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: -1: shouldn't be an issue with vs2013 vs. vs2012, and was probably not necessary in your case either. Most project types "just work" between vs2012 and vs2010.

Comment: Then why this question was appeared?

Comment: Good question. Maybe the OP is mistaken as to the nature of the problem.